# Phonegap + Youtube API Load

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, youtube-api

I've got quite a mystery here, since this was working yesterday at the end of the day. However, this morning I couldn't connect to the API, and I didn't change a thing on my code.

I'm working on a Phonegap Android app with Javascript + jQuery Mobile.

I've got this code to load the client.js:

```
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
```

Which is at the bottom of my index.html.

The handleClientLoad function is as follows:

```
function handleClientLoad() {
    $.mobile.loading("show");
    gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
        console.log('loaded!');
        $.mobile.loading("hide");
        $('#capture').fadeIn();
        navigate('home');
    });
}
```

The apiKey is defined on another file.

The callback on handleClientLoad never runs.

The creepy thing is that I CAN connect to Youtube if I run my page through MAMP, but I can't connect via phone. I've had this working for weeks via phone, it was just today that it stopped connecting.

Also, I can connect to Facebook via the app, so it's not a network problem.

Can anyone help? If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure the apis.google.com domain is allowed by phonegap in your configuration file ? Also are you sure the https protocol works with phonegap ?

Comment: Romain, my access tag is like this <access origin="*"/>, so I wouldn't say that is a problem. Also, I think the Facebook API, which I'm also using, uses https, and I never stopped having access to that one. Since my JS code didn't change and the Youtube API previously worked, I'm betting that there was some kind of change on the Phonegap configuration that messed up with my connection to Youtube... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still have no idea what caused this, but after a while everything started working perfectly again. I suppose it was a glitch from Youtube!